# How to create table in existing database with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

my infrastructure is 2 docker containers: postgres db (with user/pass/dbname parameters configured with env in docker-compose.yml) and simple flask app with form, what create new record in table. It works if table was created manually.
I need to check if_exists table on app start and create if it sends "false", but default create function on sqlalchemy create table in public, not in engine db.

I tried engine.execute("\c dbname"), but it doesn't works.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is my answer:

```
conn = engine.connect() 
metadata = MetaData(engine)

exist=sqlalchemy.inspect(engine).has_table("Products")
if exist == False:
print("=Table doesn't exist=")
products = Table('products', metadata,
            Column('id', Integer(), primary_key=True),
            Column('product', String(200), nullable=False),
            Column('price', Integer())
            )
 metadata.create_all(engine)
 print("=Table was created=")
else:
 print("=Table exists=")
 logging.info('Table exists')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).